# Sqlite source code reading. What the ids like F17025, U17032 are used for?

Tags: c, sqlite

In SQLite source code comments I see identificators like F17025, U17032, etc.

sqlite3.c:

```
** The sqlite3_mutex_enter() and sqlite3_mutex_try() routines attempt
** to enter a mutex. {F17024} If another thread is already within the mutex,
** sqlite3_mutex_enter() will block and sqlite3_mutex_try() will return
** SQLITE_BUSY. {F17025}  The sqlite3_mutex_try() interface returns SQLITE_OK
** upon successful entry.  {F17026} Mutexes created using
** SQLITE_MUTEX_RECURSIVE can be entered multiple times by the same thread.
** {F17027} In such cases the,
```

What they are used for? Probably there are some related docs?

Answer (score 1):

I think that these are references to sections of some internal document (think [Functional Requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirements)).

Comment: Strange, I googled around using that ids, but can't find such document. The project is open sourced, so it should be available, may be I am using bad keywords? Or all requirements are just in comments?

Comment: I have found some requirements doc: http://www.sqlite.org/requirements.html, but I still see no defs for F17025 ourside the code